# Is it safe to add the third wire on Dell Laptop charger to an external battery?

Tags: laptop

I wired an old secondhand Dell charger (that was making a funny noise when charging), to the laptop 19v output of a RocketSocket charger. It works great, but there's one problem... it shows charging, the battery doesn't go down, but it doesn't actually charge the laptop battery, and when I start up the computer it gives [that infamous adapter not recognized message](http://www.laptop-junction.com/toast/content/dell-ac-power-adapter-id-chip-died).

Now, I suppose I could cut open the charger and wire the chip to the third wire, but I think that may be a bad idea because according the the instruction sheet, the RocketSocket outputs 12/16/19V - 2/3.5/3.5A output. The secondhand Dell charger shows output 19.5v **4.62A**. Do I risk overheating or damaging the RocketSocket laptop charger or the Dell by faking a more powerful adapter's chip? Or can I reprogram the third wire's chip to set the correct expected amperage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the specs for "Rocket Socket" charger, it can do 12V with 3.5 A, but at 19V it can do only 2 A.

So yes, if you attach the Dallas ID chip from Dell 19V 4.62A adapter to the center wire, the laptop will think that it has the PA-10 power adapter, and will try to suck up to 4.62 A, thus overloading the "Rocket-Socket" by more than twice. The likely effect will be either the voltage will drop below 10V, or it will smoke out. The advice - don't do this, or get a more powerful power supply.

But again, why go for such a trouble if the original DELL 90W 19V/4.62A adapters are well under $10 even on Amazon?

Regarding programming or emulaing the ID chip, [there were some attempts](https://hclxing.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/hacking-a-dell-power-adapter-final-not-really/) to do so. But again, does the trouble worth it?